# How to find documents with $geowithin and then use $geonear aggregate pipeline to create distance field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I have a collection of homes in MongoDB. I want to first find all homes within a radius given a location ($geowithin) and then create a distance field on all these documents using aggregate pipeline $geonear. How do I chain these together?

```
Model.find({
location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[lng, lat], radius]} }
```

})

```
Model.aggregate([
{
  //PLEASE NOTE: GeoNear must always be the first stage in the pipeline
  $geoNear: {
    near: {
      type: 'Point', 
      coordinates: [lng, lat]
    }, 
    distanceField: 'distance', 
    distanceMultiplier: multiplier
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need `$geoWithin` at all. The `near` field of `$geoNear` would contain the same coordinates as the `$geoWithin`, yes? The `maxDistance` parameter of `$geoNear` would serve as `radius`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.